# Where is the syntax error in this bit of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**Error from firebug:**

```
missing ) after condition
[Break on this error] else if (($(this).parent...nt().hasClass('plaing')==true) ) {
```

**The code:**

```
$(".myButtonPlay").live('click',function(){
     if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('current')==false){  

       console.log($(this).children().attr('src'));
       var media=$(this).parent().parent().attr('media');
       var id=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
       $(this).parent().parent().addClass('plaing');

       $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://localhost:8000/silver/images/btn_pause.gif')
       play_media(media, id);


            }
      else if (($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('current')==true) $$ ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('plaing')==true) ) {   
     $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('plaing');
      $('#mediaPlayer').attr('player').pause();
      $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://localhost:8000/silver/images/btn_pause.gif');

          }
     else  if ( ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('current')==true) $$ ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('plaing')==false)  ){    
     $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://localhost:8000/silver/images/btn_paly.gif');
     $(this).parent().parent().addClass('plaing');
     $('#mediaPlayer').attr('player').play();

         }

});
```

Where is the problem? Looks like error is in conditions of second `if` statement....

Comment: What editor are you using? Any decent editor with parenthesis matching would help catching the error...

Comment: Eclips With  Amateras plugin.. It's work perfectly and not show me any mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, `$$` is not an operator... maybe you meant `&&`?

Comment: Ohhh мазерфакa! Thanks man... It's because i did not drink coffee today :)

Comment: no coffee, no code. "Programmers are organisms that convert caffiene into code" :)

Comment: Pulling my answer as they're the same.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

$$ is not a valid operator. Reading your code it seems like you were trying to use the && operator.

Comment: yeah, saw it after I posted my answer. Always bad when you get sidetracked while writing an answer...

Comment: You could just click `delete`. I did it. g.d.d.c did it.

Answer (score 0):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)  is your friend, or at least it want's to be.